# Number of arrangements for a 12-digit number with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

I have a combinatorics problem that I've been working on and I would like to know if my solution is correct. The problem is as follows:

Let $n$ be a 12-digit number consisting of the digits 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7. Given that each digit in $n$ occurs at least twice and at most four times, determine the total number of possible arrangements for $n$.

Here's my solution:

We can consider the number of ways to arrange the digits in $n$ such that each digit occurs at least twice and at most four times. Since $n$ is a 12-digit number, there are a few possible cases for the number of times each digit occurs:

- Case 1: Two digits occur four times and one digit occurs twice. There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose which two digits occur four times and $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to choose which digit occurs twice. Then there are $\frac{12!}{4!4!2!}$ ways to arrange these digits in $n$. So the total number of arrangements in this case is $\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1}\frac{12!}{4!4!2!}$.
- Case 2: One digit occurs four times and three digits occur twice. There are $\binom{5}{1}$ ways to choose which digit occurs four times and $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to choose which three digits occur twice. Then there are $\frac{12!}{4!2!2!2!}$ ways to arrange these digits in $n$. So the total number of arrangements in this case is $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{3}\frac{12!}{4!2!2!2!}$.
- Case 3: Four digits occur three times. There are $\binom{5}{4}$ ways to choose which four digits occur three times. Then there are $\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}$ ways to arrange these digits in $n$. So the total number of arrangements in this case is $\binom{5}{4}\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}$.

Adding up all the cases, we find that the total number of possible arrangements for $n$ is $$\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1}\frac{12!}{4!4!2!} + \binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{3}\frac{12!}{4!2!2!2!} + \binom{5}{4}\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}$$

Is my solution correct? Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are considering numbers which do not contain all of the digits $3, 4, 5, 6, 7$, you should have a case in which three digits each appear four times.  Please state the rules as clearly as possible.